# French polynesia : application can't be installed

Tags: android, google-play

I've an application restricted to France. People living in French Polynesia, using Tikiphone SAS provider, can download app but can't be installed with an error message like "Operator is not allowed".

Do you have idea ? Why these people can't install application but download it ?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your Developer Console for the Android Market that "All Carriers" is checked under France in the Publishing Options area.

Comment: apparently yes, see below. for France and others countries.